# How to update all records when before delete trigger is called?

Tags: apex, trigger, before-trigger, delete

Can anyone help me out? I store all the records of my TestObject__c in a List. My requirement is, if the user delete the record in TestObject__c and if the checkbox is check, one field in all records will be updated at the same time. But I am having a hard time updating this record.

Here is my code:

Trigger class:

```
trigger TestObjectTrigger on TestObject__c (before delete) {

    if(trigger.isBefore) {
        }  if(trigger.isDelete) {
            TestObjectHandler.metDel(trigger.old);
        }
    }
}
```

TestObjectHandler class:

```
public class TestObjectHandler {
        
        public static void metDel(List<TestObject__c> ls) {
            List<TestObject__c> allObj = [SELECT Name, hobbies__c, check__c FROM TestObject__c];
            System.debug('all: ' + allObj);
            for(TestObject__c td : ls) {
                if(td.check__c {
                   allObj.hobbies__c = 'eating';
                }
            }
            update allObj;
    
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: When you're getting an error (and you should be getting an error here), you should _always_ include the full text of the error message, verbatim.

Comment: why do you want to update records you are about to delete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`allObj` is a list.
The list contains records which have a `hobbies__c` field, but the list itself does not have that field or any other field (at least none that are publicly accessible).

so `allObj.hobbies__c` is not valid syntax.

It's not clear why, exactly, you want to do this. However, assuming there is a valid purpose here, you'd want to restructure things a bit to make things more clear and avoid doing work that doesn't need to be done (i.e. save yourself queries and DML rows)

- Loop through the records being deleted to see if any of them have your checkbox checked first (a boolean variable initialized to false would help here)
- If you did detect the checkbox being checked, *then* you query for the other records

  - You want to exclude the records being deleted (doesn't make sense to update something that is going to be immediately deleted, that's just a waste of governor limits)
- Loop through the records not being deleted, update the field
- DML update the records from the query

That's just a basic idea of one way to approach this. It ignores other important things like "what if there are more than 200 records being deleted?" and "what if there are more than 10k records that need to be updated?".

To properly handle this, you'd likely want to create a batch class (which you can [schedule a one-time run of](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_system.htm#apex_System_System_scheduleBatch_2)) to handle the update separate from the deletion; and also a static variable to hold the jobId so you can detect if you've already scheduled a batch job (so you don't try to schedule another batch job).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I greatly appreciate it! Actually, I have no particular reason why I want to update the field. I am studying and I noticed that I can't update the field. I realized the reason why I can't update the field is because I have to loop the List that I query first. Do you mind if I ask you how would you exclude the records? I'm thinking of using WHERE in soql but maybe you have a better idea.